# default printing style in browser/ web mail client

Tags: css, email, printing

I did some white text on black background design stuff on the newsletter.
Since the newsletter is gonna looks good and readable for printing.
I need to make the layout and the text are as similar as what is in the browser.

Normally, is that black text and no background color are the default printing style for browser/ web mail client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking how to create embedded style rules for printed media, you can do it this way:

```
<style type="text/css">
  @media print { … }
</style>
```

However you will need to check the supported email clients [here](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/1907/can-i-include-a-print-styleshe/)

But yes I would say the default for printing style is black text on white background.